# Python in Plone: trying to append a variable to RESPONSE.redirect

Tags: python, plone

I have a python script in Plone, I'm having trouble appending a variable to RESPONSE.redirect. I get a invalid syntax error.

```
test = '1000'

RESPONSE.redirect(("/Plone/user_blast/public_blast_results/%s" % (test))
```

Answer (score 1):

Its me being stupid, theres an extra bracket by redirect.